# SNS cross account subscription with additional layer

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-sns

We own an AWS Account, account A. We rely on an external team to publish messages to their SNS topic, which is in their account B. We use an SQS queue in account A to subscribe to the SNS topic in account B. Account A has been whitelisted by the owner of account B to subscribe to the SNS topic.

Now, we would like to subscribe to the SNS topic in Account B for multiple (new) accounts. However, the team that owns account B does not have the capacity to manually whitelist the many accounts we will be creating.

Is there a way for us to delegate or proxy permissions from account A to all the new accounts that we are creating, via something like an IAM Role created in account A?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can't rely on the owners of `Account-B` to do anything for you, then your only option would be:

- Create your own SNS Topic in Account-A (`Topic-A`) where you can manage subscriptions
- Create an AWS Lambda function that will send messages to `Topic-A`
- Subscribe the Lambda function to your existing `Queue-A`, so that any message sent to `Queue-A` will be re-sent to `Topic-A`
- Have all the accounts use `Topic-A` as if it was `Topic-B`

This way, you can use your existing SQS queue (`Queue-A`) as a 'relay' to a new SNS topic (`Topic-A`) under your control. You would also need to change your current apps that consume from `Queue-A` to consume from a new queue that is subscribed to `Topic-A`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that account B is trying to give permission to a specific user of account A.  Like you mentioned, this can be an issue if you need to setup multiple accounts.

You can solve this in multiple ways.

1. Account B gives the **root** of Account A permission.  Then, Account A has full permission to delegate the access to any IAM roles / users.  Here is a blog post contains this method of setup https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/cross-account-integration-with-amazon-sns/
2. Create an IAM group in Account A, and assign users to the group.  Then, in Account B give the permission to Account A's group instead of the specific user.  [Here is an example of providing access via groups](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_common-scenarios_aws-accounts.html)

Please note that if you are going with solution #1 that any IAM user in account A will be able to access the SNS resource.  If multiple applications are running in account A this could be an issue.

Comment: Could you clarify how accounts C, D, E are going to use this? Can account A delegate or proxy permissions to these new accounts to use SNS in Account B?

Comment: For cross-account resource access 2 things need to happen: 1) account B gives permission to account A users. 2) The users in Account A (C, D, E) need to get access from Account A to use it (through IAM).

Comment: In solution #1, giving permission to the root user allows any IAM user from that account to have access, as long as there is an IAM statement allowing them to do so

Comment: In this solution, is [role chaining used](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_session-tags.html#id_session-tags_role-chaining)? I would though that Acc B could have a role with permissions to its SNS. The role can be assumed by a role in Acc A. The role in Acc A, can be in turn assumed by other accounts. Subsequently, Acc A is just a proxy for the original role in Acc B.

Comment: No, not in the solution I provided.  I have not used that before so I'm not quite sure of the use case, but that looks to be like a temporary solution (sessions) which wouldn't solve the problem.  However, in my solution I am simply saying that you can assign permission to Acc A root user, which means any users created by Acc A would be able to gain access.

Comment: Yes, I agree. But how Acc A would delegate access to users in Acc C? I think that's the OP's issue. Thus Acc A could create a role which could be assumed by users in Acc C. This way, users in Acc C would have indirect access (through the role in Acc A), to the SNS in Acc B.

Answer (score 1):

Your current situation is:

- Amazon SQS queue (`Queue-A`) in `Account-A` owned by you
- Amazon SNS topic (`Topic-B`) in `Account-B` owned by somebody else
- Permissions have been added to `Topic-B` that allows `Account-A` to **subscribe** to the topic

The above has worked well.

New requirements:

- Allow `Account-C` and `Account-D` to subscribe to `Topic-B`
- The owner of `Account-B` does not wish to modify the permissions on `Topic-B` to allow these subscription requests

**Solution**

Instead of `Account-C` and `Account-D` sending a `Subscribe()` request, ask the owner of `Topic-B` to **directly subscribe the new queues**.

You say that *"the team that owns account B does not have the capacity to manually whitelist the many accounts we will be creating."*

This is based on the idea that `Account-C` and `Account-D` should, themselves, send the Subscribe request to `Topic-B`. Instead, I am recommending that you provide the ARNs of `Queue-C` and `Queue-D` to the team that owns `Topic-B` and ask them to add these queues as subscribers. This does *not* require any change to the permission policy on `Topic-B`.

However, a couple of things to note:

- `Queue-C` and `Queue-D` will need to *confirm* the subscription. The easiest way to do this is to view the initial message sent to the queue after being subscribed to the topic, copy the subscription URL shown in the message and then paste it into a web browser. This is a one-off process.
- `Queue-C` and `Queue-D` will need to add permission to allow `Topic-B` to send a message to their queue. You probably have this in place already for `Queue-A`. The policy would look like:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Id": "arn:aws:sqs:ap-southeast-2:ccc:my-queue/SQSDefaultPolicy",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action": "sqs:SendMessage",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:sqs:ap-southeast-2:ccc:my-queue",
      "Condition": {
        "ArnEquals": {
          "aws:SourceArn": "arn:aws:sns:ap-southeast-2:bbb:their-topic"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

See also:

- [Sending Amazon SNS messages to an Amazon SQS queue in a different account - Amazon Simple Notification Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-send-message-to-sqs-cross-account.html)
- [Using Amazon SNS for system-to-system messaging with an Amazon SQS queue as a subscriber - Amazon Simple Notification Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-sqs-as-subscriber.html#SendMessageToSQS.sqs.permissions)

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think this will work because of the constraints on the external team I mentioned. For more context, the new accounts we are creating will be 'developer' specific accounts, that will be used to deploy individual AWS stacks for development/testing. This means that each time a new developer joins the team, the external team will have to repeat the step of adding their queue, which they will not commit to.